# Finding matches in two arrays with indexOf

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am going through the FreeCodeCamp Mutations challenge. Here's what I have to do:

> Return true if the string in the first element of the array contains
>   all of the letters of the string in the second element of the array.
>
> For example, ["hello", "Hello"], should return true because all of the
>   letters in the second string are present in the first, ignoring case.
>
> The arguments ["hello", "hey"] should return false because the string
>   "hello" does not contain a "y".
>
> Lastly, ["Alien", "line"], should return true because all of the
>   letters in "line" are present in "Alien".

This is my solution. Unfortunately it isn't working, although I think it's possible to solve the problem like this. Where is my mistake?

Here is the code with my detailed comments:

```
function mutation(arr) {

  //indexOf is case sensitive, so first we make all the elements in the array lowerCase. After that we use the lowerCaseArray instead of our original array

var y = arr.join(" ");
var x = y.toLowerCase();
var lowerCaseArray = x.split(" ")

// This variable will contain the number of matches 

var matchCounter = 0;

//The for loop picks a letter from the second element
//(lowerCaseArray[1][i]) of an array and then we look
//if a match in the first element of an array(lowerCaseArray[0] is found).
//If there is a match, then the indexOf would return a number >=0.
//In this case we add 1 to our matchCounter.

for (i = 0; i < lowerCaseArray[1].length; i++) {
  if(lowerCaseArray[0].indexOf(lowerCaseArray[1][i]) > 0) {
    matchCounter+= 1;

  }

//Finally we compare the matchCounter length with the second
//element of our array.  If matchCounter >= the length of our
//array, it means every letter in the second element was found
//within the first element

}
return matchCounter >= arr[1].length;

}

mutation(["floor", "for"]);
```

For some reason `return lowerCaseArray[1][i];` returns 'o', although the last letter of the second element is "r". And in the given example `matchCount` equals 2, but it should be 3, because there are 3 matches. Maybe this is the part with a mistake.

Comment: I ran your code and it properly goes through all 3 letters, `f`, `o`, and `r`. Can you run again and verify?

Comment: It does, but it returns false because the matchCounter equals 2 instead if 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line causing your code to return the wrong result is this one:

```
if (lowerCaseArray[0].indexOf(lowerCaseArray[1][i]) > 0) {
```

It ignores the possibility that the sought character could be in the 0 position.

Changing the `>` to `>=` gets it to work. Your comments actually indicate that it should be `>=`, but your code uses `>`.

There are a few other places where the code could be made a bit less convoluted. See below:

```js
function mutation(arr) {

  //indexOf is case sensitive, so first we make all the elements in the array lowerCase. After that we use the lowerCaseArray instead of our original array

  var lowerCaseArray = arr.map(function (str) {
      return str.toLowerCase();
  });

  // the for loop checks each letter in the second string
  // if any of its letters is not present in the first one,
  // return false immediately
  for (i = 0; i < lowerCaseArray[1].length; i++) {
    if (lowerCaseArray[0].indexOf(lowerCaseArray[1][i]) === -1) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  // if the for loop completed without returning, then the strings pass the test.
  return true;
}

console.log(mutation(["floor", "for"]));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check for unequal `-1`, because zero `0` is a valid index of the string.

```
if (lowerCaseArray[0].indexOf(lowerCaseArray[1][i]) !== -1) {
//                                                  ^^^^^^
```

```js
function mutation(arr) {
    var y = arr.join(" "),
        x = y.toLowerCase(),
        lowerCaseArray = x.split(" "),
        matchCounter = 0,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < lowerCaseArray[1].length; i++) {
        if (lowerCaseArray[0].indexOf(lowerCaseArray[1][i]) !== -1) {
            matchCounter += 1;
        }
    }
    return matchCounter >= arr[1].length;
}

console.log(mutation(["floor", "for"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(lowerCaseArray[0].indexOf(lowerCaseArray[1][i]) > -1)?
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also use `regex`. This will also save you trouble of matching case.

**Sample**

```js
function validate(arr){
  var regex_str = arr[0].replace(/[^a-z0-9 ]/gi, function(m){ return "\\" + m }) 
  var regex = new RegExp("^[" + regex_str + "]*$", "i");
  var valid = regex.test(arr[1]);
  console.log(regex, "|", arr[1], "|", valid)
  return valid
}

validate(["floor", "for"])
validate(["floor", "fora"])
validate(["heworld", "hello World "])
validate(["heworld", "hello World "])
validate(["heworldts(*) ", "hello World (test *)"])
```

Comment: This would break if the first string contained characters like `\` or `]`.

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks for pointing it out. Please check the update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once match('sIng','Singer').

```
var match=function(a,b)
{
    var nomatch=0;
    var w1=a.toLowerCase(); 
    var word1=w1.split('');
    var string2=b.toLowerCase();
    console.log('word1 len : '+word1.length+' '+string2+' length : '+string2.length);
        for(var i=0;i<word1.length;i++)
    {
        if(string2.indexOf(word1[i])==-1)
        {
            console.log('no match : '+b+' .indexOf('+word1[i]+')');
            nomatch +=1;
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('match : '+b+'.indexOf('+word1[i]+')');

        }
    }
    if(nomatch>0)
    {
        console.log(b+' does not have all  characters of '+a);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(b+' do have all  characters of '+a);
    }

}
match('hello','Hell');
```